# LibreOffice Writer - captions crop figures

Tags: image, caption, libreoffice-writer

I am creating a report meant to be read/edited by MS Word. To do that I have created it from scratch and saved as .docx.

In this report I am including some images together with captions. All of the captions were added manually. Everything went fine, I have saved the document and closed Writer.

Now I want to put my hands on it again and, upon opening the report, this is what I am seeing:[image: The cropped figure]. Previously the figure was showing fine inside the text box (that inserting a caption creates). The text box is in the same position and size, but there appears to be a boundary over which it just displays white. I can reduce the figure's size inside the boundary of visibility, and a glimpse of the captions appears too [image: The resized image.].

Note that the red arrow disappears too.

Needless to say, I can not work on a 100+ pages document and then check again each picture, delete it and re-create it, check again the cross references and so on. I would much rather work with LaTeX, but I am required to deliver a .docx file.

I am working on Ubuntu 20.04, Libreoffice is updated to version 6.4.6.2 and the only plugins I have equipped it are TexMath and Zotero.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same thing. It seems to be an issue already in Libreoffice Writer between Linux and Windows. If you create a document on Linux with a cropped image and then open the file in Libreoffice on Windows the cropping of that image is already messed up. Happens to me with Libreoffice Version 6.3.5.2.

Comment: This bug might be the reason for the crop issue: https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=84800
The solution for now could be to set the Windows scale factor to 100%